# Prevent Code-Formatting in Eclipse by HotKey

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, formatting, hotkeys

I knew one can prevent the code formatting in eclipse by surrounding the code with

```
// @formatter:off
// my awesome formatted code...
public Set<Person> transformCustomersToPersons(List<Customer> customers){

    Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        persons.add(new Person(
                customer.getFirstname(),
                customer.getLastname(),
                customer.getTitle(),
                customer.getBirthday(),
                customer.getAddress(0).getCity(),
                customer.getAddress(0).getStreet(),
                customer.getAddress(0).getHousenumber(),
                customer.isMan() ? "m" : "w",
                customer.getCardNumber())
        );
    }
    return persons;
}
// @formatter:on
```

But I don't want to write it manually all the time. It would be perfect just mark the code, press a hotkey and the code gets prevented from formatting.

Anybody knows how? Thx!

Comment: +1. I didn't know about this feature :)

Comment: It's just Eclipse's way of letting you know you should have a person-from-customer method in this case ;) Which you should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is possible:

Create new template: 
`Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates->New` (screenshot)

[image]

Give a name to the template something like `non-formater` and put the Pattern:

```
   // @formatter:off
   ${line_selection}${cursor}
   // @formatter:on
```

Now, you can select the text and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and a number of the template - here <kbd>4</kbd>

[image]

Comment: +1, Great explanation. this is so much clear and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own hot-key by defining a key sequence, using extension points.
To see and edit Keyboard shortcuts in eclipse: Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Keys.

Add a key for your perusal and thus thereby select the codes and run this hotkey.